# %%xtshortdate%% not working in email studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio

I'm trying to create an email create an email in Marketing Cloud's Email Studio that includes the current date in the body. Per [this page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5) I put %%xtshortdate%% into a free form content block, but when I send a test email it doesn't convert. It's worth noting that some personalization strings, such as %%member_state%% (as shown below), work fine, but none of the date personalization strings work. Below are screenshots of what I put in the content block and what shows up in the test email.[image: email html] this is how it appears in my test email 
 [image: email]

Comment: Did you try a real send rather than a test send? If this does not work in a real send either try https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Now.htm

Comment: You're correct, for some reason it works in a real send but not a test send